# I am trying to make a smart contract in solidty to pool user funds and then transfer them to AAVE lending

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets, aave

This is my code. I am not very familiar with solidity.

Currently I am just using a hard coded interest rate instead of deriving it from AAVE for testing

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

interface ILendingPool {
    function deposit(address _reserve, uint256 _amount, uint16 _referralCode) external payable;
    function getReserveData(address _reserve) external view returns (uint256 totalLiquidity, uint256 availableLiquidity, uint256 totalBorrows, uint256 liquidityRate, uint256 borrowRate, uint256 aTokenAddress, uint40 lastUpdateTimestamp);
}

contract EthDepositPool is Ownable {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    uint256 public totalPooledEth;
    uint256 public contractFund;
    address lendingPoolAddress;
    address cryptonicsTokenAddress;
    address nftContractAddress;
    uint256 lastInterestDistribution;
    uint256 public constant INTEREST_RATE = 2; // 2% interest rate
    uint256 public constant DISTRIBUTION_INTERVAL = 1 minutes; // Change as needed

    event EthDeposited(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    event EthWithdrawn(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    event InterestDistributed(uint256 interestAccrued);

    constructor(address _lendingPoolAddress, address _cryptonicsTokenAddress, address _nftContractAddress, uint256 _initialFund) Ownable(msg.sender) {
        lendingPoolAddress = _lendingPoolAddress;
        cryptonicsTokenAddress = _cryptonicsTokenAddress;
        nftContractAddress = _nftContractAddress;
        contractFund = _initialFund * 1 ether;
        lastInterestDistribution = block.timestamp;
    }

    function depositEth() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Must deposit some ETH");
        totalPooledEth += msg.value;
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value; // Track user's deposited ETH amount
        emit EthDeposited(msg.sender, msg.value);
        
        // Mint NFT representing the user's deposit and transfer it to the user
        uint256 tokenId = totalPooledEth; // Example: Use totalPooledEth as tokenId (Change as needed)
        UserSharesNFT(nftContractAddress).mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
    }

    function withdrawEth(uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        require(_amount > 0 && _amount <= address(this).balance, "Invalid amount");
        totalPooledEth -= _amount;
        payable(owner()).transfer(_amount);
        emit EthWithdrawn(owner(), _amount);
    }

    function lendEth(uint256 _amount) external payable onlyOwner {
        require(_amount > 0 && _amount <= totalPooledEth, "Invalid amount");
        IERC20(lendingPoolAddress).approve(lendingPoolAddress, _amount);
        ILendingPool(lendingPoolAddress).deposit{value: _amount}(address(0), _amount, 0);
    }

    function distributeInterest() external onlyOwner {
        require(block.timestamp >= lastInterestDistribution + DISTRIBUTION_INTERVAL, "Distribution interval has not elapsed yet");
        lastInterestDistribution = block.timestamp;
        uint256 totalNFTs = ERC721Enumerable(nftContractAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalNFTs; i++) {
            uint256 tokenId = ERC721Enumerable(nftContractAddress).tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address(this), i);
            address holder = ERC721Enumerable(nftContractAddress).ownerOf(tokenId);
            uint256 userBalance = balances[holder];
            uint256 interestAccrued = (userBalance * INTEREST_RATE) / 100;
            contractFund -= interestAccrued;
            CryptonicsToken(cryptonicsTokenAddress).mint(holder, interestAccrued);
            emit InterestDistributed(interestAccrued);
        }
    }
}

contract UserSharesNFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC721("UserSharesNFT", "USNFT") Ownable(msg.sender) {}
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(_to, _tokenId);
    }
}

contract CryptonicsToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("Cryptonics", "CPT") Ownable(msg.sender) {}

    function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        _mint(_to, _amount);
    }

    function balanceOfUser(address _user) external view returns (uint256) {
        return balanceOf(_user);
    }
}
```

For the code I keep on getting the error:

```
transact to EthDepositPool.depositEth errored: Error occurred: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Error provided by the contract:
OwnableUnauthorizedAccount
Parameters:
{
 "account": {
  "value": "0x1c7962aC91d54EAb55853b7d26fA97cb98BD9078"
 }
}
```

I have changed the code multiple times and I have encountered this error.
This is the latest iteration of the code I have been working on. Apart from this, suggestions and any kind of guidance would also be helpful.
Help would be appreciated as I have been working on this from the past 10 hours and still could not find anything to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't approve your contract to be the users tokens spender. The following code is wrong:

```
token.approve(address(this), requiredAllowance);
```

It approves contracts token to be spent by the contract itself.

The user must explicitly send approval transaction to allow your contract to spend those tokens, and it must occur before deposit  transaction.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work

Comment: Still thx for the help